# malloc(): corrupted top size on recv() method from Linux

Tags: c++

```
PacketStructure receive(int fd) {
    byte buffer[512];

    // recv() is from Linux/UNIX system
    int lng = recv(fd, (char*)buffer, 512, 0);
    if (lng <= 0) throw lng;

    PacketStructure packet = {};

    // do some stuff

    return packet;
}
```

When `lng` is zero, it crashes on throwing `lng`.

I cannot handle it in `try / catch` statement when I call `receive()` method.

It probably crashes before catching.

When it crashes I get: `malloc(): corrupted top size`.

Comment: If your socket is non-blocking, then 0 is an expected return.  In any case, a packet is almost never the right thing to process.  Normally you call recv in a loop until you get the amount of data dictated by the protocol, independent of packet boundaries.

Comment: @stark "*If your socket is non-blocking, then 0 is an expected return*" - no, it is not. 0 means the connection was closed by the peer. If the socket were to block, recv() would return -1 instead and errno would be set to EWOULDBLOCK or EAGAIN, depending on implementation.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing wrong with this function. The problem is likely somewhere else. `malloc` is known to crash when you made mistakes in prior memory allocations or deallocations.

Comment: @JohnDoe: That doesn't change my answer. `malloc` is known to **crash** your whole application. `try/catch` deals with C++ exceptions, and can catch a `std::bad_alloc` from `new`. But that's only on memory exhaustion, not when you made mistakes like mixing `free` and `delete`.

Comment: When you corrupt the heap the bug can be in any part of the code that has executed before the corruption is detected.

Comment: @JohnDoe One of the most annoying things about programming is the location of the crash site often has little relationship with the location of the bug that ultimately caused the crash. It is not uncommon to have an error that initially slips through the cracks and has effects that become visible thousands of lines of code and weeks of runtime later.

Comment: @user4581301 I suggest compiling your code with [AddressSanitizer](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer) enabled. That should instantly tell you where the issue is. You could (should) also enable [UBSan](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer.html) to catch undefined behavior. This works on both GCC & Clang (no idea about MSVC).

Comment: @Darhuuk wrong user.  The asker is John Doe.

Comment: As for me, I use it when I can. ASAN is not available on too many platforms I need to support.

Comment: @user4581301 Ah yes, sorry, my mistake. Unfortunately my comment is too old to be edited now.